# Phone Number Mask - Internationals

Tags: ms-access, vba, input, mask

My Problem

My Customer Contact Database has a variety of customers from around the world in it, and this causes some problems for my telephone numbers - because of the different methods of formating in other countries. So my question is, firstly since I also have a country field - Is it possible to have the type of mask change based of what country the customer is in?

Example:

```
In Canada -> (xxx)xxx-xxxx
In Australia -> (xx) xxxx-xxxx
In South Africa -> xx (x) xx-xxx-xxxx
```

*x - A placeholder for numbers*

Would this be possible?

Comment: It's a computer. Of course it's possible. Right now, however, we have no way to help you because you haven't told us what these numbers are used for, why you need them to be formatted a specific way, etc. Do you need to display this on a website? Do you need to save it to a database?

Comment: @HK1 I wanted to preserve the comments you made on my deleted answer. I will delete these, too, if you prefer.  Here is the first: I built a system like this and stored the input masks in my table, tblCountries. Here are some examples: Australia: !0\-0000\-0000;;_ Hong Kong: !0000\-0000;;_ Poland: !00\-000\-00\-00;;_ Brazil: !00\-0000\-0000;;_ Spain: !000\-000\-000;;_

Comment: and the second: One of the problems you'll run into is that many countries have variable length phone numbers. I ended up making a Dialing Notes field and filling it in with information like: All phone numbers in Hong Kong are 8 digits long.

Answer (score 1):

Hans mentioned he couldn't get the Input Mask to change at runtime - I haven't seen his previous answer, but this seems to work for me. My form has a drop-down for country (cmbCountry), and a text box for phone. My combo box (cmbCountry) is tied to a table (Row Source=`SELECT [_ masks].Country, [_ masks].Mask FROM [_ masks];`). The "masks" field is hidden by having its' width be zero.

I've also bound the form to a table which stores the countries and phone numbers. When the country changes, or the record changes, I change the ListIndex property.

FYI - I did *not* give the Input Mask any default value in Design mode.

@HansUp, is this similar to what you had already? Sorry if I'm re-answering the question in the same way.

In the code behind the form:

```
Private Sub cmbCountry_Change()
    Dim sMask
    If cmbCountry.ListIndex > -1 Then
        sMask = cmbCountry.Column(1, cmbCountry.ListIndex)
        tbPhone.InputMask = sMask
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    cmbCountry_Change
End Sub
```

Comment: Similar enough, but mine didn't apply the equivalent of your `tbPhone.InputMask = sMask` ... no error message, but the InputMask didn't change.  So I saved the form after removing the InputMask in Design View as you suggested.  And then my code did change the mask at runtime.  However I then saved the form with a mask, and back in Form View my original worked after all.  I don't know where I went wrong before.

Comment: Maybe you can re-post your original answer so @Colin can give you the points?

Comment: Thanks, but no.  Yours is better.